# Problems converting NAD83 UTM to lat and long

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-maps, gis, utm

**Edit** So the solution I posted from Jenner at VBforums was, obviously, in VB, and I used an online converter to port it to C#. Something was lost in translations, and that's why it was 10 miles off.

I'm guessing I am just misunderstanding what the algorithms at the Proj.Net discussion boards are for and that's why they weren't doing what I wanted them to.

I will close this question out in two days when I can mark my answer unless someone provides something awesome.

---

I am having issues converting UTM to lat and long. As an example, I have the following NAD83 UTM coordinate:

Easting: 686029.702258

Northing: 3581213.621173

zone: 15

A solution I found on [vbforums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=529828) a while ago gives me a point about 10 miles south of where I would expect it. A simple mathematical solution I found [here](http://projnet.codeplex.com/discussions/77458), is giving me unexpected results.

```
double[] inverseMercator (double x, double y) {
     double lon = (x / 20037508.34) * 180;
     double lat = (y / 20037508.34) * 180;

     lat = 180/Math.PI * (2 * Math.Atan(Math.Exp(lat * Math.PI / 180)) - Math.PI / 2);
     return new double[] {lon, lat};
}
double[] toPoint = inverseMercator (686029.702258, 3581213.621173);
```

I get the following result:

lat: 30.602349476368449

long: 6.1627096689832594

I get similar results using the Proj.Net solution provided by D_Guidi in the same thread.

Using an online converter, I was able to get something closer to what I am expecting:

lat: 32.35238307052292

long: -91.0230710652583

Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong?

Edit - would prefer .NET solutions or something that would be easily convertible

[Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689836/converting-utm-wsg84-coordinates-to-latitude-and-longitude)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I posted from Jenner at VBforums was, obviously, in VB, and I used an online converter to port it to C#.  Something was lost in translations, and that's why it was 10 miles off.

I'm guessing I am just misunderstanding what the algorithms at the Proj.Net discussion boards are for and that's why they weren't doing what I wanted them to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the cs2cs binary contained in "proj" (projection, http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/)?  I believe that will do an accurate job converting UTM to easting/northing and lat/lon.  The trouble is simple math formula do not accurately, enough, account for the shape of the earth.

Comment: I'll check it out - I should have specified originally that it's a .NET project, but I'll see if I can make this work

Comment: I believe proj can be compiled for Windows. It's easy enough to call out to it as an external executable, though a little clunky.  Good luck.