# X/Y Coordinates to Longitude/Latitude, package for .net core app

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude, geo

I have a task to convert some incoming geo data to Longitude/Latitude.  The data elements in the json are identified as xCoordinate and yCoordinate.

However, the data in my sample does not look like any geographic x/y coordinate data I've looked at online, so I have a couple questions that I could use expert help on, please forgive the lack of knowledge regarding this data, I've never worked with geo data prior.

An example from my sample dataset:

- xCoordinate: 0981829
- yCoordinate: 0197525

Couple questions:

- Do these look like valid X/Y coordinates?  Online examples seem to be in decimal format.
- I need a package to import into a .net core application which converts X/Y data to Longitude/Latitude, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This might be UTM, but you would need to know zone to convert to lat/lon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system. Is there anything resembling zone info in this dataset?

Comment: @MichaelEntin I just received some further info from a colleague, who referred me to www.earthpoint.us/StatePlane.aspx, and in using this site, he was able to successfully map a conversion from State Plane to Lat/Long.  Our zone used would always be the same.  Does that info help?  Are there any .net core packages that you're aware of that can make this conversion?  Thanks very much for the response.

Comment: check this question - it has link to couple libraries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689836/

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=proj4net and https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial